# Heroku Python Webapp - pip is not found, and runtime is default despite runtime.txt

Tags: python, git, heroku, web-applications, deployment

I am a novice and don't understand many of the concepts, so excuse me if there are some ambiguities or plain fallacies in my statements and questions.

I am writing a web app using Flask python framework. I have already tested it on localhost. Now I want to deploy it to heroku's webserver.

Here is the folder where the main files are stored:

```
static #this is a folder
templates #this is a folder
Procfile
requirements.txt
runtime.txt
app.py
```

Now here are the contents of Procfile, requirements.txt and runtime.txt respectively:

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

requirements.txt:

```
 Flask==0.12.2
 gunicorn==19.7.1
 itsdangerous==0.24
 Jinja2==2.9.6
 MarkupSafe==1.0
 Werkzeug==0.12.2
```

runtime.txt:

```
 python-2.7.1
```

Now, it was python-3.5.1 in runtime.txt , before I had the problem but now during debugging I've left it as 2.7.1, because there's another problem I find.

Now when I try to execute the command: git push heroku master, the following ouptut is generated:

```
Counting objects: 13, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 1.95 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 13 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.5.1
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:     

/app/tmp/buildpacks/{somelonghash}/bin/steps/pip-
install: line 7: /app/.heroku/python/bin/pip: No such file or 
directory

remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to joecrownwebapp.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/joecrownwebapp.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 
'https://git.heroku.com/joecrownwebapp.git'
```

Where **{somelonghash}** was some long hash which for the purposes of this question I've removed. Now as you can see first the app is being deployed with python-3.5.1 which is strange given the fact that I've specified in runtime.txt that the runtime should be for example 2.7.1. Now we also see that pip is being installed and thereafter the requirements are being installed with pip and that is where the problem occurs.

The first question that comes to my mind is:  Where exactly is this *"/app/.heroku/python/bin/pip:"* directory supposed to be, or for that matter *"/app/tmp/buildpacks/{somelonghash}/bin/steps/pip-
install"*?

Are they somewhere on my machine? (I figure not because if they are unix-based pathnames, then app should be directly under root, but I dont have such a folder)

If they are not on my machine where are they, how can I locate them and examine them. Are they somewhere on the Heroku server. If so, where does my problem arise from? Why is my *runtime.txt* disregarded?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!